# How to change the screen background color in SwiftUI mac app?

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

I have a following code:

```
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(users) { user in
                    HStack {
                        NetworkImage(
                            url: URL(string: "https://via.placeholder.com/100x100")
                        ).frame(width: 50, height: 50).cornerRadius(8.0)
                        Text(user.name)
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Users")
        }.onAppear {
            self.getUsers()
        }
    }
```

Now, how do I remove this translucent background in list view and use solid color like white?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can us **listRowBackground()** modifier to apply colours the List.

```
List {
    ForEach(0..<10) {
        Text("Row \($0)")
    }
    .listRowBackground(Color.red)
}
```

Above is the Simple ListView and for your code ==

```
var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(users) { user in
                    HStack {
                        NetworkImage(
                            url: URL(string: "https://via.placeholder.com/100x100")
                        ).frame(width: 50, height: 50).cornerRadius(8.0)
                        Text(user.name)
                    }
                }.listRowBackground(Color.red)
            }
            .navigationTitle("Users")
        }.onAppear {
            self.getUsers()
        }
    }
```

I hope this would work for you.

Comment: It produces result like this https://i.imgur.com/tvs3ITF.png. How do I also add color to the padding around listview?

Comment: try ```.colorMultiply(.red)``` instead of ```.listRowBackground(Color.red)```

Comment: I did that but the scroll is now messed up. Also `Color.white` doesn't work

Comment: Yeah full white

Answer (score 0):

Late answer...

Have you tried to embed your List in a `ZStack`? And applying a Color view before the List?

```swift
var body: some View {
            NavigationView {
                ZStack {
                    Color.white.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all) //<--- HERE!
                    List {
                        ForEach(users) { user in
                            HStack {
                                NetworkImage(
                                    url: URL(string: "https://via.placeholder.com/100x100")
                                ).frame(width: 50, height: 50).cornerRadius(8.0)
                                Text(user.name)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    .navigationTitle("Users")
                }
            }.onAppear {
                self.getUsers()
            }
        }
```